# IPFS: Symbolic links in MFS

Tags: ipfs

Is there a symlink equivalent for IPFS's Mutable File System? For example, if I have a file:

```
/source/file.txt
```

and I copy it another folder:

```
ipfs files cp /source/file.txt /reference/file.txt
```

the two files will refer to the same object. If I make a change to `/source/file.txt` the copy in `/reference/file.txt` will still point to the old version. Is there a good way to make it point to the current version of the file in `/source/`?

I could keep track of all the copies and update them whenever I change the original, but that doesn't sound fun. I could also store the string "/source/file.txt" in `/reference/file.txt` and manually dereference each time I want to access the file. Better, but still cumbersome. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time being, there is no support for symnlinks in MFS: you need to track and update them manually in userland. Current MFS implementation uses immutable identifiers (CID) and each directory's CID is based on hashes of its children, so storing string in a file sounds like the most optimal way, as it does not trigger DAG recalculation every time you update the target file.